# Convert PHP to ASP.Net for file upload

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, image, file-upload

I'm trying to allow users to upload an image to my site.  I found a demo but it is written in PHP.  I am using CSHTML in Webmatrix, and it doesn't seem to be compatible with the PHP file.  Does anyone have any resources, recommendations, or links to information for writing a similar code as below but in a compatible format to Webmatrix/ASP.NET?  Also, is there a way to rename the file when it's uploaded and save it to a certain location?

Are there any security precautions I should take when allowing users to upload to the site?

```
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);

if ($fn) {

   // AJAX call
   file_put_contents(
      'uploads/' . $fn,
      file_get_contents('php://input')
   );
   echo "$fn uploaded";
   exit();

}
else {

   // form submit
   $files = $_FILES['fileselect'];

   foreach ($files['error'] as $id => $err) {
      if ($err == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
         $fn = $files['name'][$id];
         move_uploaded_file(
             $files['tmp_name'][$id],
             'uploads/' . $fn
         );
         echo "<p>File $fn uploaded.</p>";
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use fileupload.js

```
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="file" name="resume" onchange="onChangeResume()"  id="txtImageUpload"  style="width: 76px;"  />

function onChangeResume(){
    $('#txtImageUpload').fileupload({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/CandidateManagement.aspx/ImageUpload',
                    autoUpload: true,
                    done: function (e, data) {

                        //Statements 

                    }
                });
}
```

code behind

```
  HttpPostedFileBase resume = Request.Files["txtImageUpload"];
        if (resume != null && resume.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(resume.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Resumes"), fileName);//you can give what ever you want
            resume.SaveAs(path);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I'm not really sure where to place the above codes.  I'm working with the drag and drop model from sitepoint found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/.  Based on that method, where should I insert your suggested code?  Thanks.